# Unexpected behavior of PreIncrement when querying associations

Tags: functions, associations, query

For reasons I won't go into here, I became curious about the what would happen should I make a  query that applies `PreIncrement` to one key in a list of associations. I admit that it could be argued that `PreIncrement` should not be used in this way. In fact, because `PreIncrement` is `HoldFirst` and expects a symbol bound to a value, I was rather expecting Mathematica to complain about what I was about to do.  I couldn't see how Mathematica was going to find such a symbol in the situation I was setting up.

The list of associations I will use is

```
assocs = {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 3|>, <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 1|>};
```

and the query I will make is

```
Query[All, "b", PreIncrement] @ assocs
```

The first evaluation.

```
result = Query[All, "b", PreIncrement] @ assocs; {result, assocs}
```

> ```
> {{4, 3, 2}, 
>  {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 3|>, <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 1|>}}
> ```

Surprise. No complaints from Mathematica and the result seems reasonable. Now I'll do it a couple of more times.

```
result = Query[All, "b", PreIncrement] @ assocs; {result, assocs}
```

> ```
> {{5, 4, 3}, 
>  {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 3|>, <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 1|>}}
> ```

```
result = Query[All, "b", PreIncrement] @ assocs; {result, assocs}
```

> ```
> {{6, 5, 4}, 
>  {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 3|>, <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 1|>}}
> ```

This is very strange. I expected `result` to have the same value after each evaluation. Since none of the associations in `assocs` is modified by the query, what is `PreIncrement` actually incrementing?

Comment: For what it's worth `++assocs[[All, "b"]]` appears to work correctly.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. That's a good observation, but everyone should understand that your code in no way involves the `Query` mechanism. The behavior you report is a simple effect of the associations in `assocs` being destructively modified, so there is no mystery about where the incremented values are coming from.

Comment: Right, I just meant that: (1) for some purposes it is a solution (2) the fact that it works as desired but `Query` does not makes me think that the latter is a bug.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I have updated the question's title to make clear that `Query` is a big part of the issue. As to `Slice` not being in a state of grace, I feel nervous about the way it's implemented. 1) Should it memoize? This thread seems to show that doing so can be dangerous (at least to anybody expecting functional behavior). 2) Can a function that depends on another function called ``Internal`UnsafeQuietCheck``ever be fully trusted?

Answer (score 8):

The [2nd example given under Query > Properties & Relations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html#183965402) tells us

> Before being applied, `Query` expressions are "compiled" into ordinary compositions of ordinary Wolfram Language functions and their operator forms. To see the compiled form of a `Query`, use `Normal`.

That seems like a good line of exploration. Let's see where it leads.

```
Query[All, "b", PreIncrement] // Normal
```

> ```
> Map[GeneralUtilities`Slice["b"] /* PreIncrement]
> ```

And, yes, that function can be used in place of the query I've been using.

```
Map[GeneralUtilities`Slice["b"] /* PreIncrement] @ assocs
```

> `{7, 6, 5}`

Let's try for more information.

```
?? GeneralUtilities`Slice
```

[image: info]

Satori. `` GeneralUtilities`Slice `` is doing memoization. The queries do not extract values from `assocs` except when the first evaluation of `Query` is done.

This could cause real trouble. It would be good to have a way to remove the memoization. The following will work for this particular example.

> ```
> SubValues @ GeneralUtilities`Slice = 
>     DeleteCases[SubValues @ GeneralUtilities`Slice, RuleDelayed[_, _Integer]]
> ```

The behavior reported in the question also applies to `Increment`, `Decrement`, `PreDecrement` and to the use of all such operators with data sets.